# Rolling 3 previous months with unique counts after groupby in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

The following is the dataframe

```
Date        Name     data
01/01/2017  Alpha     A      
02/01/2017  Alpha     A
03/01/2017  Alpha     B
01/01/2017  Beta      A
01/20/2017  Beta      D
03/01/2017  Beta      C
04/01/2017  Beta      C
05/01/2017  Beta      B
```

Expected Output:

```
Date        Name     data
Jan 2017     Alpha     1      
Feb 2017     Alpha     1
Mar 2017     Alpha     2
Jan 2017     Beta      2
Mar 2017     Beta      3
Apr 2017     Beta      1
May 2017     Beta      2
```

I am looking for unique counts of "data" group by "Name" on 3 month rolling basis. Consider the example of "March 2017" and "Name" -> "Beta". So the months considered are Jan 2017, Feb 2017, March 2017 for the Name "Beta". The unique count is 3. Similarly for others. **Please note that count of "data" should be unique for those 3 months**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I thought `df.groupby('Name').apply(lambda x: x.resample('M').rolling(3).nunique())` after `pd.to_datetime('Date')` at first...but `.nunique()` doesn't exist there. So I've tried simple `.apply(lambda x: len(x.unique()))` right after `.rolling(3)`, but it just returned original data(A, A, B, C) unlike my expectation 3 which is the result of len(set(AABC))...it seems `.apply()` can only handle float under rolling object. I will also wait the solution.

Comment: Correct that is what has caught me too. I trying some work arounds than rolling.

Comment: apparently `pandas.rolling` can not handle spans which have no fixed lenght (like months). Even doing `df.sort_index().rolling('3M').size()` (Date as index) results in `ValueError: <3 * MonthEnds> is a non-fixed frequency` So I fear you will have to do it by looping over the months  in the `Date` column

Comment: I can get to a second DataFrame with month as index and Name as columns by `df.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper('M'), 'Name', ])['data'].apply(set).unstack().resample('M').transform(lambda x: x)`

Answer (score 2):

Group per month and `Name`, unstack and resample to month, so all months are present and you get a column per `Name`

```
df2 = df.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper('M'), 'Name', ])['data'].apply(set).unstack().resample('M').sum()
```

> df2

```
Name        Alpha   Beta
Date        
2017-01-31  {A}     {A, D}
2017-02-28  {A}     None
2017-03-31  {B}     {C}
2017-04-30  None    {C}
2017-05-31  None    {B}
```

## Multiple iterator

some itertools magic to iterate multiple times over the same column

```
def multiple_iterator(iterable, r=2):
    iterators = itertools.tee(iterable, r)
    try:
        for i, it in enumerate(iterators):
            for j in range(i):
                next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        return None
    return iterators
```

## The real work

```
def get_unique_items_rolling(df, period):
    for col_name, col in df2.iteritems():
        s = pd.Series()
#         print(f'---{col_name}---')
        for idx, *iterators in zip(col.index[period-1:], *multiple_iterator(col, period)):
            result = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(i for i in iterators if pd.notnull(i) and i))
#             print(idx, result)
            s[idx] = result
        yield col_name, s
```

> `df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_items(get_unique_items_rolling(df2, period))`

```
            Alpha   Beta
2017-03-31  {A, B}  {A, D, C}
2017-04-30  {A, B}  {C}
2017-05-31  {B}     {B, C}
```

> `df3.stack().apply(len)`

```
Date        Name 
2017-03-31  Alpha    2
            Beta     3
2017-04-30  Alpha    2
            Beta     1
2017-05-31  Alpha    1
            Beta     2
dtype: int64
```