# Rolling count of unique values on a grouped dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to calculate the number of unique customers per product over a rolling window (2 days) from sales data containing the date of the sale, the product, and a customer id. The data looks like this:

```
Date       Product     Customer     
20200101   A           '101'
20200101   B           '101'
20200101   A           '102'
20200102   A           '101'
20200102   B           '103'
20200103   A           '101'
20200103   B           '102'
20200104   B           '101'
20200104   A           '103'
20200104   B           '103'
20200105   A           '102'
20200105   A           '101'
```

The ideal output should then look similar to this, where the values are the number of unique customers over a 2-day window:

```
           A     B  
20200102   2     2    
20200103   1     2
20200104   2     3
20200105   3     2
```

I was hoping something like

```
df.groupby([pandas.Grouper(key='Date', freq='D'), 'Product'])['Customer'].rolling('2D', on='Date').nunique()
```

would work, but to start I get the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid on specified as Date, must be a column (of DataFrame), an Index or None
```

and I also now that `nunique()` does not work with `rolling`. However, I've used the approach in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44815995/rolling-3-previous-months-with-unique-counts-after-groupby-in-pandas-dataframe) but I'm afraid it won't scale very well computationally. My dataset has about ~10 million lines of sales info, and when testing on just a tenth of the total data the linked solution took me about 10 minutes to run. Any tips out there for a more efficient solution?

Thanks a lot!